# Looking for an equivalent of weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.WsdlcTask Ant Task for JBoss for generating web service Java classes from WSDL (JAX-WS)?

Tags: ant, jboss, weblogic, jax-ws

I have an Ant build file to be ported to work for JBoss. It has a following taskdef that I need to find a Weblogic agnostic implementation for:

```
<taskdef name="wsdlc" classname="weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.WsdlcTask">
        <classpath>
            <path refid="weblogic.tools.classpath"/>
        </classpath>            
</taskdef>
```

It's used as follows in the build file (package and wsdl are parameters supplies):

```
<wsdlc
                srcWsdl="res/wsdl/@{wsdl}"
                destJwsDir="lib/myws"
                destImplDir="build/ws/src"
                packageName="@{package}" 
                type="JAXWS" />
```

Would appreciate help in finding out if there is any other Ant task that I could use to remove the Weblogic one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JBoss provides the `wsconsume` script. Please check the following URL for more info:
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/wsconsume